# How to get list of ids when using groupingBy in java lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, grouping, aggregate

Lets say we have an object `User`:

```
public class User {
    private Integer id;
    private Integer age;
    private String name;
    private String family;

    public User() {}

    public User(Integer id, Integer age, String name, String family) {
        this.id = id;
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
        this.family = family;
    }

    // getters and setters emited for brevity
}
```

and i write lambda expression like below to get age average of objects based on grouping some fields:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<User> allUsers = new ArrayList<>();

    allUsers.add(new User(1, 25, "Rasool", "Ghafari"));
    allUsers.add(new User(2, 27, "Ali", "Sohrabi"));
    allUsers.add(new User(3, 25, "Ali", "Azizkhani"));
    allUsers.add(new User(4, 25, "Rasool", "Asadi"));
    allUsers.add(new User(5, 27, "Ali", "Rasooli Sa'd Abad"));
    allUsers.add(new User(6, 26, "Rasool", "Ameri"));

    Map<List<Object>, Long> groupedResult = 
        allUsers.stream().collect(
            groupingBy(
                u -> Arrays.asList(u.getName()),
                averagingDouble(User::getAge)
            )
        );

    // result:
    // {[Rasool] = 25.33, [Ali] = 26.33}
}
```

Now, i want to add something this lambda, but doesn't know how to do it. i want to get list of `id` of grouped objects in each group, may be something like this:

```
// {[Rasool, [1, 4, 6]] = 25.33, [Ali, [2, 3, 5]] = 26.33}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-. That will give you a Map<List<Object>, Set<Integer>>. The count is just the size of the Set<Integer>.

Comment: Well, the example in this documentation does it. Replace `count()` in your code by `mapping(User::getId, toSet())`, and you get a Map<List<Object>, Set<Integer>>. The count is just the size of the Set.

Comment: if i want to use `averagingDouble(User::getAge)` instead of `counting`, how can i do that?

Comment: please check my question again, i updated question

Comment: You would need to write a custom collector that would aggregate the IDs and compute the average

Answer (score 1):

a little change is enough:

```
Map<List<Object>, List<User>> groupedResult =
        allUsers.stream().collect(
                groupingBy(
                        u -> Arrays.asList(u.getName(), u.getAge()),
                        Collectors.toList()
                )
        );
```

Comment: please check my question again, i changed question completely